# Does Kotlin custom get execute method call

Tags: android, kotlin

To increase the readability of calls to SharedPreferences.Editor I want to use a Kotlin variable that will execute 'getSharedPreferences.edit()' each time I need a new SharedPreferences.Editor. Initially I was going to use something like this:

```
val editPreferences: SharedPreferences.Editor = Application.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
```

But then I was informed that 'editPreferences' will hold the reference to the same editor when what I really want it to create a new editor each time the 'editPreferences' is called.

If a custom getter was used would a new editor be returned each time? Something like this:

```
val editPreferences: SharedPreferences.Editor 
    get() = Application.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
```

Still getting up and running with Kotlin and am not sure if the get() method would hold reference to the editor instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second property declaration suits your needs: it has a [custom getter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters), thus getting the property value will always execute the getter, and the value is not stored (the property has no [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)).

You are probably confused by equals sign in `get() = ...`, but it is just a [single-expression shorthand](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) for the equivalent form of getter:

```
val editPreferences: SharedPreferences.Editor 
    get() { 
         return Application
              .getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
              .edit()
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you implement a property with a custom getter, it will not store any data. The body of the getter will be executed every time you access the property.

Answer (score 6):

You could go one step further and wrap the property with a delegate, making use of the variable name on the meta data.

#### Usage

```
class SomeActivity : SomeBaseActivity {

     // Declare property the with key "myImportantNumber" 
     // and default value 10
     var myImportantNumber by preference(10)

     //how to access the property
     fun isMyImportantNumberReallyHight() = myImportantNumber > 100

     //how to edit the property
     fun incrementMyImportantNumber(times:Int){
         myImportantNumber = myImportantNumber + times
     }
}
```

#### Delegation

The delegate keeps an instance of some preferences manager and uses the meta data on the property to fetch and save values on the shared preference.

```
class DelegatedPreference<T>(val default: T, val contextProvider:()-> Context) {

    val manager by lazy { PreferencesManager(contextProvider()) }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): T {
        return manager.get(prop.name, default)
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: Any) {
        manager.save(prop.name, value)
    }

    class TypeNotImplementedException(val propName:String) : Exception("Type of ${propName} is not implemented on DelegatedPreference and thus invalid")
}
```

#### Some sugar

A little extension method:

```
fun <T> Activity.preference(default:T):DelegatedPreference<T>{
    return DelegatedPreference(default, {this})
}
```

Which allow us to change this:

```
var myImportantNumber by DelegatedPreference(10, {this})
```

By something more readable:

```
var myImportantNumber by preference(10)
```

#### The actual getting and saving

Here what I called `PreferencesManager` (sorry I didn't come up with a better name) does the heavy lifting, and calls `.edit()` each time a property needs to be altered. It would look something like:

```
public class PreferencesManager(context: Context) {
    private val preferences = getSharedPreferences(context)

    companion object Utils {
        public val APP_PREFERENCES: String = "APP_PREFERENCES"

        fun getSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
            return context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        }
    }


    public fun save(label:String, elem:Any){
        when(elem){
            is Int     -> preferences.edit().putInt(label, elem).apply()
            is String  -> preferences.edit().putString(label, elem).apply()
            is Float   -> preferences.edit().putFloat(label, elem).apply()
            is Boolean -> preferences.edit().putBoolean(label, elem).apply()
            else -> throw DelegatedPreference.TypeNotImplementedException(label)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST", "IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_ANY")
    public fun <T> get(label:String, default:T):T = when(default){
        is Int     -> preferences.getInt(label, default)
        is String  -> preferences.getString(label, default)
        is Float   -> preferences.getFloat(label, default)
        is Boolean -> preferences.getBoolean(label, default)
        else -> throw DelegatedPreference.TypeNotImplementedException(label)
    } as T

}
```

There is a lot of room for improvement here (like parametrizing the preference name instead of hardcoding it, giving an extension point for serializing other types, etc), but the general idea remains.

Comment: creating a framework for every problem is not the most practical way go

Comment: This is hardly a framework, just a solution to a recurrent problem on the platform. And it's an interesting way to learn about Kotlin and what can we achieve with its features.

Comment: OP stated he/she is still learning Kotlin, it wouldn't be right to just talk about short term solutions or quick-fixes when we could use the opportunity to learn new things!

Answer (score 3):

As [hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36366900/2898715) and [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36366859/2898715) mentioned, a custom getter would cause a new editor to be returned each time, which is what you want.

However, please consider this extra-fancy solution that uses:

- [inlining](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) to reduce the overhead of calling the function
- [extentions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to make it seem like a method of the `Context` class even though we didn't define it
- [higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) to enable us to rid the to call `commit()` afterwards when using it

## Declaration

```
inline fun Context.editPreferences(preferenceFileName:String = "preferences",block:SharedPreferences.Editor.() -> Unit)
{
    val editablePreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editablePreferences.block()
    editablePreferences.commit()
}
```

## Usage

```
Application.editPreferences()
{
    putBoolean("SOME_BOOLEAN",true)
    putFloat("SOME_FLOAT",293232F)
}
```

or in many cases, when the receiver is already a `Context` you can do this:

```
editPreferences()
{
    putBoolean("SOME_BOOLEAN",true)
    putFloat("SOME_FLOAT",293232F)
}
```

Kotlin ❤

Comment: Also, using a function with receiver as a parameter for `editPreferences` would be even more DSL-like here (type `SharedPreferences.Editor.() -> Unit`).

Comment: Please make the function the `inline` to reduce overhead.