# Kotlin val difference getter override vs assignment

Tags: kotlin, getter

I started playing arround with Kotlin and read something about mutable val with custom getter. As refered in e.g [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/05/30/mutable-vals-in-kotlin/) or in the [Kotlin Coding Convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties) one should not override the getter if the result can change.

```
class SampleArray(val size: Int) {
    val isEmpty get() = size == 0  // size is set at the beginning and does not change so this is ok
}

class SampleArray(var size: Int) {
    fun isEmpty() { return size == 0 }  // size is set at the beginning but can also change over time so function is prefered
}
```

But just from the perspective of usage as in the guidelines where is the difference between the following two

```
class SampleArray(val size: Int) {
    val isEmpty get() = size == 0  // size can not change so this can be used instad of function
    val isEmpty = size == 0        // isEmpty is assigned at the beginning ad will keep this value also if size could change
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36366900/3883569) answer I could see that for getter override the value is not stored. Is there something else where the getter override is different form the assignment? Maybe with delegates or latinit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your second example `size` is immutable value and therefore both ways are valid.

However variant with overridden getter `get() = size == 0` [has no backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters) and therefore `size == 0` is evaluated every time you access `isEmpty` variable.

On the other hand, when using initializer `= size == 0` the expression `size == 0` is evaluated during construction (check exactly when and how here - [An in-depth look at Kotlin’s initializers](https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546)) and stored to the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), of which value is then returned when you access the variable.

Comment: What would the difference be if the getter function example was a declared as a  `var`?

Comment: According to documentation, there would be no effect in the example cases above. When using `val` the setter is _not allowed_, when using `var` you _can_ (optionally) implement the setter - if you don't, then the default `field` identifier will be used ([Backing fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields)). But because you implemented custom getter, this `field` has no use (unless you use it in getter).

Comment: What's a backing field?  The kotlin docs don't explain it.

Answer (score 12):

The key difference here is that in `val isEmpty get() = ...` the body is evaluated each time the property is accessed, and in `val isEmpty = ...` the expression on the right hand side gets evaluated during the object construction, the result is stored in [the backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) and this exact result is returned each time the property is used.

So, the first approach is suitable when you want the result to be calculated each time, while the second approach is good when you want the result to be calculated only once and stored.

Comment: What is a backing field?  Your link doesn't explain it.

Comment: It's a field that stores the value of a property. It can be either mutable or immutable (`final` in JVM terms).