# Kotlin CoroutineScope initialization depending upon CoroutineContext with custom getter

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, coroutinescope

The google codelab *Android Room with a View - Kotlin* has the following [snippet](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#8):

```
class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    // ...

    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
       get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    // ...

}
```

And from what I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433608/kotlin-val-difference-getter-override-vs-assignment/45433909#45433909) answer, the custom getter is evaluated everytime, whereas the assignment is evaluated at the time of constructing only. So in effect, `scope` would take a value that wouldn't change later, so what use is the custom getter for `coroutineContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `coroutineContext` as a computed property (or custom getter) makes more sense when you are defining a `CoroutineScope` in a component with  lifecycle (i.e. Android `Activity`). The example in the **Javadoc** is self-explanatory:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel() // Cancel job on activity destroy. After destroy all children jobs will be cancelled automatically
    }
}
```

In this case, you are creating the `Job` in a lifecycle method, that's why you need the computed property to return the `coroutineContext` with the `Job` instance created in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this example we can get rid of

```
private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
   get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main
```

and just write

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.Main)
```

So the result code will look like:

```
class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var parentJob = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.Main)
    // ...
}
```

I guess it is a matter of style to write getter in this case. Nothing will change if we remove it.